Does my dogs spay incision look ok? It's very irritated
My dog got spayed 10 days ago. The incision line looks like it's healed together nicely but there is bumps at either side of the knots which look red and inflamed.
.

You need to contact your vet, not a bunch of untrained internet strangers.

@AllisonC I have! But he either doesn't respond or responds with short answers such as "looks ok"

Then ask another vet

We've had similar questions here: This one was no concern as blisters can appear when the sutures are absorbed by the body, but this one needed a vet. I'm not a vet and cannot say if the wound "looks ok" or if your dog needs additional veterinary care. The cut certainly looks bigger than normal and this amount of scabbing is also more than we usually see here. If in doubt, ask a different vet for a second opinion.
